# Bypassing Bogo routing when using timber get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

I am using Timber get_posts method and Bogo-localization add on in my WordPress based application. The application is localized to multiple languages using Bogo. The different version of the application is accessed via urls that contain the desired locale for example wwww.myapplication.com/en, wwww.myapplication.com/sp, wwww.myapplication.com/ge etc. There is also an unlocalized or default language version of application. I also have bunch of posts in the database with post type of 'product'. These posts do not contain any localizable data so there is no need to create localized versions of them. My question is can I access unlocalized versions these posts from the localized version in my application?  For example the code below works fine when accessed from wwww.myapplication.com, but when I try access it for example from wwww.myapplication.com/ge the results variable is empty.

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );
 $resultss = Timber::get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query parameters did the trick.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby'   => 'date',
'order'     => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'suppress_filters' => true
);
$resultss = Timber::get_posts($args);
```